# Comma in "new, difficult role"

Tags: punctuation

I was told to remove the comma when I wrote:

> He resigned from his job and took on the new, difficult role.

Is this comma optional? Or is putting it up there wrong? As I understand, if the two words can be switched around while retaining the meaning of the sentence, then a comma is required. "Difficult new role" sounds ok to me.

Comment: Could you post the entire sentence? That would make it easier to answer. It's hard to answer your question with such a short fragment as an example. Generally, a comma is used to separate two consecutive adjectives, but that is falling out of favor. There are times in which the comma is necessary. I agree with you at this point. To my ear, it needs a comma without using *and* to join them.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use a comma between adjectives that are describing the same word - role.

Comment: Then what about *red American car*? Both – *red* and *American* – are describing *car*, but I have found that most would not suggest a comma.

Answer (score 1):

A *new difficult role* is a particular difficult role that is new, perhaps unlike other difficult roles.  The word *new* modifies *difficult role*:

> new [ difficult [ role ] ]

A *new, difficult role* is a role that is both difficult and new.  The coordination *new, difficult* modifies *role*:

> ( new, difficult ) [ role ]

The comma forces the latter interpretation.  Without the comma, the former interpretation is most likely, but (I think) not forced.

Comment: Wouldn't "new difficult role" suggest that his previous role was also difficult? Rather than a "new, difficult role", which would be a new role, that is also difficult in comparison to his previous role/other roles.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comma is better omitted because the adjectives refer to quite different characteristics of the role. Compare

> He bought the large[,] blue shirt.

I think most would omit the comma. In particular, most speakers will not be pausing at that point in the sentence. On the other hand

> He bought the gigantic, enormous shirt.

Here the adjectives overlap in meaning, the comma looks right, and a speaker is likely to pause to wind up an even more emphatic tone for the second adjective.